# Java Applet compiles very well but does not run

Tags: java, applet

What is wrong with this Java `Applet`, even tho I compile it with no issue it does not run.

```
import java.applet.*;//Importing java.applet
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
   TextField txt1, txt2;
   public void init(){//Initializing our applet
       txt1 = new TextField(""); //Creates a textfield 'txt1'
       txt2 = new TextField(""); //Creates a textfield 'txt2'
       setBackground(Color.CYAN);//Setting background color to CYAN
       add(txt1); //Adds textfield 'txt1' to your applet
       add(txt2); //Adds textfield 'txt2' to your applet
   }
   public void paint(Graphics obj){//Paint method to display our message
       String s1 =  txt1.getText(); //Fetching data from text field 1.
       String s2 =  txt2.getText(); //Fetching data from text field 2.
       int num1=0, num2 = 0, num3;   //Declaring 3 integer variables    
       num1 = Integer.parseInt(s1); //Parsing the string value of text field 1 to integer
       num2 = Integer.parseInt(s2); //Parsing the string value of text field 2 in integer
       num3 = num1 + num2;       //Performing addition
       String s3 = String.valueOf(num3); //Converting the result from integer to string
       obj.drawString("Result:", 40, 50);
       obj.drawString(s3, 50, 50);//To display the result
   }
}
```

Comment: When debugging applets, it is vital to see the output in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml).  Don't use AWT components in the 3rd millennium, use Swing.  Don't paint in a top-level container, use a `Canvas`/`Panel` or `JPanel`.  Don't code an applet unless the GUI has to be crammed into a web page - writing/debugging code for frames is easier.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect a `NumberFormatException` is being thrown.

After all, *any time the applet tries to paint itself* - including immediately after initialization - you'll be running this code:

```
// Comments removed as they were more distracting than useful. You really
// *don't* need to comment variable declarations to say they're declarations...
String s1 =  txt1.getText();
String s2 =  txt2.getText();
int num1=0, num2 = 0, num3; 
num1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
num2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

So when `txt1.getText()` returns an empty string, which it will before the user has had a chance to type anything, you're going to be parsing that empty string, which will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

It feels to me that the general design of this applet is inappropriate. Why would you want to use `drawString` for what are essentially labels?

I would add either one or two `Label` controls - either one for the complete text "Result: " and the result, or one for just "Result: " and a separate one for the result. Then you don't need to override `paint()` at all - you can instead add handlers for *when the textbox contents change* - which is, after all, the only time you need to change anything.

You should then put the `Integer.parseInt` call into a try/catch block, catching `NumberFormatException`. (You could also consider using a `NumberFormat` instead of `Integer.parseInt`, but you can do that later...)

Comment: "any time the applet tries to paint itself" and and run itself without processing any events :)

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is the strings couldn't be painted properly. The `paint` method calls by the applet several times before you have any input. So, the textfields has empty strings. This because a `NumberFormatException`. Check the text for empty value. If you parse numbers add `try/catch` block. In addition moving the logic to the method `calculate` with `repaint` and initiating it when you make input. This could be happen if you add some listeners to the textfields.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.TextEvent;
import java.awt.event.TextListener;//Importing java.applet
public class MyApplet extends Applet
{
  TextField txt1, txt2;
  String s3;
  public void init()//Initializing our applet
  {
    txt1 = new TextField(""); //Creates a textfield 'txt1'
    txt2 = new TextField(""); //Creates a textfield 'txt2'
    txt1.addTextListener(new TextListener(){
      public void textValueChanged(TextEvent e) {
        calculate();
      }
    });
    txt2.addTextListener(new TextListener(){
      public void textValueChanged(TextEvent e) {
        calculate();
      }
    });
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);//Setting background color to CYAN
    add(txt1); //Adds textfield 'txt1' to your applet
    add(txt2); //Adds textfield 'txt2' to your applet
  }

  void calculate(){
    try {
      String s1 =  txt1.getText(); //Fetching data from text field 1.
      String s2 =  txt2.getText(); //Fetching data from text field 2.
      int num1=0, num2 = 0, num3;  //Declaring 3 integer variables
      num1 = Integer.parseInt(s1); //Parsing the string value of text field 1 to integer
      num2 = Integer.parseInt(s2); //Parsing the string value of text field 2 in integer
      num3 = num1 + num2;          //Performing addition
      s3 = String.valueOf(num3); //Converting the result from integer to string
      repaint();
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){}

  }
  public void paint(Graphics obj)//Paint method to display our message
  {
    super.paint(obj);
    obj.drawString("Result:", 100, 100);
    if (s3 != null)
      obj.drawString(s3, 150, 100);//To display the result
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in :

```
txt1 = new TextField("");
txt2 = new TextField("");
```

as

```
String s1 =  txt1.getText(); 
String s2 =  txt2.getText();
num1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
num2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

will not be able to parse `""` and will `throw exception` as explained by Jon Skeet.

So the **fix** could be a `try catch` block(Exception handling):

```
try{
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
   }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
```

OR have some initial parseable `String` value

```
txt1 = new TextField("0"); 
txt2 = new TextField("0");
```